# This was supposed to get an image in the array and resize it before printing it out to the frame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, bufferedimage

The cods first goes to the array and gets the file name. Then it converts it to a Buffered Image and changes the size of the image. It then sends the array of pictures to the main method where it is converted to a JLabel before adding it to the frame. I understand my programming convesion skills are kinda lacking but it would be nice if you could explain why when i run this i the image isnt resizing

This is the main class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    
    
    public Frame(JLabel welcomeImage)
    {
        setTitle("Tower Defence Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(750 , 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(welcomeImage);
    }
    
    
    public static JLabel WelcomeImage(Image[] pics)
    {
        
        pics[0].getScaledInstance(750, 1000, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon WelcomeImage = new ImageIcon(pics[0]);
        
        JLabel JWelcomeImage = new JLabel();
        JWelcomeImage.setIcon(WelcomeImage);    
        
        return JWelcomeImage;   
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        
        Image[] pics = Images.Image();
        JLabel welcomeImage = WelcomeImage(pics);
        JFrame frame = new Frame(welcomeImage);
    }

}
```

This is the class that would hold all the images

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Images
{
    
    public static Image[] Image() throws IOException
    {
        //Getting all the Picture in a png format 
        String Picture[] =  {"apple.png"};
        
        //Getting the Picture as an image
        Image[] Pics = new Image[Picture.length];
        
        BufferedImage iPic;     
        BufferedImage oPic;
        
        //Using a for loop to put the Picture in an array
        for(int i = 0; i < Picture.length; i++)
        {
            iPic = ImageIO.read(new File(Picture[i]));
            oPic = new BufferedImage(750 , 500 , iPic.getType());
            Pics[i] = (Image) oPic;
        }
        
        return Pics;
        
    }

    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> it would be nice if you could explain why when i run this i the image isnt resizing

Well, the first thing is to learn how to display the image at its actual size BEFORE attempting to scale the image. You can't display a scaled image if you don't know how to display the default image.

The problem with your code is that you can't even display the actual image, so trying to display a scaled image has no chance of working.

With that in mind you have several structural issues:

1. Don't call you class "Frame". There is an AWT component with that name and it is confusing. A class name should be more descriptive.
2. Don't extend JFrame. You should only extend a class when you add functionality to the class. Adding components to a frame is not adding functionality,
3. Components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.
4. Don't use setSize(). How can the frame size and the image size be the same? The frame contains a titlebar and borders so it must be larger. Instead you should be using `pack()` before the setVisible(...) statement.
5. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Be consistent.
6. Method names should be descriptive. What does the "Image" method do. Nobody could guess by looking at the method name. Maybe something like "readImages" or "loadImages"?

**In the Image class:**

```
iPic = ImageIO.read(new File(Picture[i]));
oPic = new BufferedImage(750 , 500 , iPic.getType());
Pics[i] = (Image) oPic;
```

What is the point of the "oPic" variable. The purpose of this method is to read the image, not scale the image. The "oPic" variable just contains an empty BufferedImage.

So get rid of that variable and just add the "iPic" image to the array.

**In the Frame class:**

```
pics[0].getScaledInstance(750, 1000, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
ImageIcon WelcomeImage = new ImageIcon(pics[0]);
```

The above code does nothing because the `getScaledInstance(...)` returns a new instance of the Image. So you need to assign it to a variable before you can use it:

```
  //  pics[0].getScaledInstance(750, 1000, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
  //  ImageIcon WelcomeImage = new ImageIcon(pics[0]);
  Image scaled = pics[0].getScaledInstance(750, 1000, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
  ImageIcon WelcomeImage = new ImageIcon(scaled);
```

I suggest you learn Swing basics by reading the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). Each section contains examples and the code will be better structured. The examples will show you how to create a class without extending JFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just some clarification needed, can you give me an example when you would call your class Frame and extends JFrame :)

Comment: I said you should NOT extend JFrame. I don't know of any reason to extend JFrame. A frame is just a container for other components.